# How to make Rider show API documentation again?

Tags: .net-core, rider

Since reinstalling with Fedora 32, Jetbrains Rider does not show XML documentation for external APIs like all the SDK classes and methods anymore:

[image]

As you can see, Rider does not show the method documentation, even though [I know it's there](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Span.cs#L421) and the Rider decompiler does show it too, when Ctrl+Clicking into the `Slice` method.

The official `dotnet-sdk-3.1` package from the Fedora repositories is installed and works as normal.

Is there some setting that I missed and which allows me to fix/enable the documentation?

Comment: Because I don't think it's my fault, I've now reported it as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-46311

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue disappeared after 2 weeks of system upgrades and restarting. No idea what caused this.